# Is there a way to see the free space directly in Files browser?

Tags: files, samba

I have a network drive which i access via smb.
I can see the free space like this:

```
storm@Ustorm:~$ df -h /run/user/1000/gvfs/smb-share:server=r9000.local,share=movies%20ssd
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
gvfsd-fuse      458G  408G   50G  90% /run/user/1000/gvfs
```

Is there any way,application or add-on to see the free space, directly in 
[Files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSCvg.png) ?

Comment: Doesn't Right-click -> Properties show it?

Comment: I know that, if possible i'd wish to be displayed directly without additional click/commands, like in windows when you mount a share it displays it directly in My Computer, with a blue bar indicating size/available....very convenient.

Comment: Ubuntu 19.1
storm@Ustorm:~$ uname -a
Linux Ustorm 5.3.0-29-generic #31-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 17 17:27:26 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
i'm using default File manager that came with Ubuntu: Files 3.34.1-stable

Comment: No way with the application itself currently. Would be nice if on "Other Places", they would also list mounted volumes along with the available space, as has been implemented for "Computer" since version 3.19.1